# change innerHTML to nearby document

Tags: javascript, include, innerhtml

I would like to have a section of my webpage's contents to change upon a button click.  However, the content I'd like to have change includes formatting itself, and I would prefer to have the content in a separate document.

I would like it to look something like this, but I'm okay with any solution:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function swap() {
  document.getElementById('toChange').innerHTML = '<!--#include virtual="../newContent.htm"-->';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="toChange">Temp Text</span>
<input type="button" onclick="swap()" value="Change" />
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is obviously with the include statement in swap() but I don't know how to change it appropriately. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically server side includes don't work in this context; you will have to resort to AJAX requests.

You didn't tag your question with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), but you could read up what it does behind the scenes:

```
function swap() {
    $('#toChange').load('../newContent.htm');
}
```

[`jQuery.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) reads the contents from `../newContent.htm` using an AJAX call and then stores that HTML inside the `toChange` span.

Comment: Right, I don't know jQuery yet; do I need to include anything else in the header to make this code work?

Comment: @user1535846 Yeah, just add this in the `<head>` - `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know your probably going to need JSON and AJAX for your request. I do know that changing the data content without making a new request is what JSON and AJAX are used for mostly. It will update the page dynamically without reloading. JSON is built-in to Javascript so your actually on the right path. Hopefully it helps somewhat.